# find all occurrences of pattern(s) after last occurrence of another pattern before line X

Tags: regex, bash, awk, sed, text-processing

Sounds a little bit complicated, but actually it isn't. Let's say we've got the following (apache2 config) file:

```
[...]

 <VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:80>
   ServerName one.domain.tld
   ServerAlias 1.domain.tld

   DocumentRoot "/path/to/anything"
   [...]
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost 321.321.321.321:80>
   ServerName two.domain.tld
   ServerAlias 2.domain.tld

   DocumentRoot "/path/to/something/else"
   [...]
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost 123.123.123.123:443>
   ServerName one.domain.tld
   ServerAlias 1.domain.tld
   ServerAlias secure.one.domain.tld
   ServerAlias secure.1.domain.tld

   DocumentRoot "/path/to/anything"
   [...]
 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost 321.321.321.321:443>
   ServerName two.domain.tld
   ServerAlias 2.domain.tld
   ServerAlias secure.two.domain.tld
   ServerAlias secure.2.domain.tld

   DocumentRoot "/path/to/another/something/else"
   [...]
 </VirtualHost>

[...]
```

---

I need to know the (sub)domains pointing to each document root. It's important for me to process each `DocumentRoot` seperately as I need to run certain commands in the for loop. I made an approach with `bash` and some additional programs like the following:

```
DOCROOTS="$(egrep -ni '^(DocumentRoot|[ ]*DocumentRoot|\t*DocumentRoot) ?=' ${HTCONF} |sed -r 's/(DocumentRoot|"|'"'"'| |   )//gI')"
for DOCROOT in $(echo "${DOCROOTS}"); do
  LINE="$(printf ${DOCROOT} |cut -d':' -f1)"
  ROOT="$(printf ${DOCROOT} |cut -d':' -f2)"
  DOMAINS=$(sed "${LINE},\$d" ${HTCONF} |tac |sed '/VirtualHost/Iq' |tac |egrep -i 'ServerAlias|ServerName' |sed -r 's/(ServerName|ServerAlias| |   )//gI')

  [... rest of document root specific code goes here ...]
done
```

Explanation:

1. store all DocumentRoot definitions and their line number to variable `DOCROOTS`
2. for every line in `DOCROOTS` do:

   1. set variable `LINE` to line number
   2. set variable `ROOT` to document root
   3. `sed "${LINE},\$d" ${HTCONF}` - this deletes everything after `$LINE`
   4. `tac` - this works pretty much like `rev`, but not just reversing the content of one line, but the complete input
   5. `sed '/VirtualHost/q'` - this deletes everything after the line containing `VirtualHost` case insensitively
   6. `tac` - this reverses the complete input back to it's original order
   7. `egrep -i 'ServerAlias|ServerName'` - this catches lines containing `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` only
   8. `sed -r 's/(ServerName|ServerAlias| |  )//gI'` - this removes the `ServerName` and `ServerAlias` directive case insensitively as well as spaces and tabs.

---

Desired output of a `printf "${ROOT}\n${DOMAINS}\n\n"` would then be something like this:

```
/path/to/anything
one.domain.tld
1.domain.tld

/path/to/something/else
two.domain.tld
2.domain.tld

/path/to/anything
one.domain.tld
1.domain.tld
secure.one.domain.tld
secure.1.domain.tld

/path/to/another/something/else
two.domain.tld
2.domain.tld
secure.two.domain.tld
secure.2.domain.tld
```

---

Is there a better way to achieve this (maybe with `awk`)?

Is `bash` the wrong way to do this? Should I consider using a proper scripting language? If so, which one would be recommendable?

Comment: what is your expected match or outupt?

Comment: for any complex text processing `awk` is usually (> 95%) the proper tool.

Answer (score 2):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk  '/VirtualHost/{s=RS} 
 /Server(Name|Alias)/{s=s $2 RS} 
       /DocumentRoot/{gsub("\"",""); print $2,s}' file

/path/to/anything
one.domain.tld
1.domain.tld

/path/to/something/else
two.domain.tld
2.domain.tld

/path/to/anything
one.domain.tld
1.domain.tld
secure.one.domain.tld
secure.1.domain.tld

/path/to/another/something/else
two.domain.tld
2.domain.tld
secure.two.domain.tld
secure.2.domain.tld
```

**Explanation**
The structure of this `awk` script is pattern{action} pairs (similar to if/then statements).  I aggregates the second fields for lines containing Server(Name|Alias) and when finds a DocumentRoot prints the path with aggregated fields.  The aggregate field is reset at VirtualHost.  The initial value and joins are record separator (RS), by default is new line.  Additionally, while printing it strips the quote signs.

Frankly, there is not much to explain further.  Perhaps one trick, the set up of the aggregation this way (instead of say `s=s RS $2` generates the empty lines between groups by default.

Comment: Could you please explain the corresponding parts?

Comment: Also, this does not work the way intended. Output: http://pastebin.com/raw/6VWFRRT6

Comment: @David you didn't provide the expected output for your posted sample input so we are guessing at what you want. If your posted sample input doesn't accurately represent your real input/output then fix your question to demonstrate the issues, don't just add a link to some file on some other site and expect us to figure it all out from that. Make sure your question includes concise, TESTABLE sample input/output that we can run a potential solution against to prove whether or not it works.

Comment: sorry, can't access to your link, but that's the output I got based on the input you provided.

Comment: Oh, I misinterpreted your solution. It's not doing what I was looking for.^^ I need to operate each DocumentRoot seperately in a for loop.

Comment: Also, the question includes the complete input and the answer I posted before contains the exact output I was looking for.

Comment: Great, now move that output plus the script that produces it to your question (and delete your answer) and you'll have a [mcve] and then we can start to help you figure out the right approach. Though it looks to me like @karakfa's answer produces the same output as your "answer" so idk why you're saying karakfa's doesn't do what you want.

Comment: Because my approach generates the output `DocumentRoot` by `DocumentRoot`, which is what I need to operate certain specific commands seperately for each DocumentRoot.

Answer (score 1):

It's still not entirely clear but it sounds like what you need is:

```
$ cat tst.awk
{
    gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
    name = value = $0
    sub(/[[:space:]].*/,"",name)
    sub(/[^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]*/,"",value)
}

name ~ /^Server/ {
    flds = flds ORS value
}

name == "DocumentRoot" {
    gsub(/^"|"$/,"",value)

    print value flds
    print "doing rest of document root specific code ..."
    print ""

    flds = ""
}
```

.

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
/path/to/anything
one.domain.tld
1.domain.tld
doing rest of document root specific code ...

/path/to/something/else
two.domain.tld
2.domain.tld
doing rest of document root specific code ...

/path/to/anything
one.domain.tld
1.domain.tld
secure.one.domain.tld
secure.1.domain.tld
doing rest of document root specific code ...

/path/to/another/something/else
two.domain.tld
2.domain.tld
secure.two.domain.tld
secure.2.domain.tld
doing rest of document root specific code ...
```

It really all depends what "rest of document specific code" is - if it's more text manipulation it belongs in awk but if something else it belongs in shell.

Comment: This works pretty well. I feel a little bad, though, because I think I didn't provide enough information on what I mean. I modified my code by now to do a lot more and it's quite... unclean. But I don't know if this is the right place to post it and ask for better solutions? Also, I think it might be a new question, then, because both solutions are perfectly working for the original question.

Comment: Accept one of the answers here and post a new question with it's own [mcve] including concise, testable sample input and expected output. You can reference this question in your new question but don't make people come and look at it to find code, input, or output - write your new question to stand alone.